# How to make sure Flyway loads before my bean?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, flyway, spring-ioc

I have a Spring Boot application in which a Bean loads configuration-data from the database.

Right now I set up this Bean in the Configuration class. But it seems it loads before `Flyway`.

How to make sure `Flyway` has finished it's job *before* my beans get loaded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can initialize it before you start Spring Boot application:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Init Flyway here
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

Second option is to use `@DependsOn` annotation for your beans depending on Flyway.

Comment: Probably I can also create e Flyway bean myself in the Config class, and have it @Ordered before my Beans ... ?

Comment: I updated my answer. `@Ordered` seem to be used for different purpose.

Comment: Strangely, Flyway did just not autoconfigure in my application. I have now created the bean manually, and used @DependsOn("flyway") for my Bean.